# Visual Basic : Random String Generation

Tags: visual-studio-2012

this is my first time asking for help here at StackOverflow.

I've been trying to work on a project which allows random string generation. Although it is working, I'm trying to find out how to add special character(s) after a certain amount of characters that have been generated.

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim pool As String = ""
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    pool = ""

    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        pool = pool & "0123456789"
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        pool = pool & "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    End If
    If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
        pool = pool & "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    End If
    Dim count = 1
    Result.Text = ""

    Dim cc As New Random
    Dim strpos = ""
    While count <= Length.Text
        strpos = cc.Next(0, pool.Length)

        Result.Text = Result.Text & pool(strpos)
        count = count + 1

    End While
End Sub
End Class
```

Now, I can generate the string, but I'm looking to find out how to add hyphens. For example I get "XikclCwXrPBd8RL35oaoN5LNW" when the string is generated at twenty-five characters. What I can't figure out, is how to add hyphens every fifth character, which it would look like this, "Xikcl-CwXrP-Bd8RL-35oao-N5LNW."

If I were to add code which generates hyphens every fifth (or any custom amount) character, would I have to redo my code again, or is the solution to my problem simple?

Thanks, and I hope this question isn't too much of a hassle.

Here is also a screenshot of my project.
http://puu.sh/aEgus/0309527a1e.png
I don't have "at least 10 reputation to post images."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
While count <= Length.Text
    strpos = cc.Next(0, pool.Length)

    Result.Text = Result.Text & pool(strpos)

    If count MOD 5 = 0 And count < Length.Text Then
        Result.Text = Result.Text & "-"
    End If

    count = count + 1

End While
```

I'm not sure if the VB syntax is good as I never coded VB before but I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out. It also takes care of not adding a hyphen at the end.

Comment: The `If` statement requires a `Then` and I believe the MOD check needs to be done before adding a new character otherwise in this case you would have it added in the wrong place ie starting at character 6 instead of character 5.

Comment: `count` has an initial value of `1`. My sample will insert a hyphen after inserting 5 letters exactly as in the question example: "Xikcl-CwXrP-Bd8RL-35oao-N5LNW".

I added the `Then` (as I mentioned in the answer I'm not familiar with VB syntax). I don't think that a syntax error is worth a downvote by the way, a comment was more than enough.

Comment: @Zammalad I actually get an expression error with the "==" using your solution from above "While count <= Length.Text
    strpos = cc.Next(0, pool.Length)

    If count MOD 5 == 0 Then
        Result.Text = Result.Text & "-"
    End If

    Result.Text = Result.Text & pool(strpos)
    count = count + 1

End While"

Comment: @Gabriel Apologies I missed the count initialization. Your method is indeed correct

Comment: @NoNameBlank Sorry yes it should be a single = sign not == (classic C++ coder mistake) This solution by Gabriel will work though, use that.

Comment: @NoNameBlank It's because you need to use a single equal instead of the double one. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: This above code does work, but when I try to "generate" I still have no hyphen within my string.

Comment: I also get an expression error with "&&" but if I just use a single "&" the code works, but no hyphen, hmm.

Comment: My bad VB uses `And` instead of `&&`. This time I created a quick VB console app and tested my code, it's generating the exact same string than in your example.

Comment: @Gabriel your code is working now. After the "&'s" was changed to "And" (why did I not think of this, I have no idea.) I'm getting a perfect string generation now.

Comment: One last thing, "If count Mod 5 = 0 " Could I make "5" a variable which can be changed in my form, changing the 'insert hyphen at character amount?' Such as, inserting hyphen every 3, or 6 characters, without having to change code? I'm trying to add a textbox now which will insert a hyphen every 'custom character amount.'

Comment: Yes you'll just need to replace `5` by a variable, something similar to what you did with `Length.Text`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, @Gabriel your solution works wonderfully. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking to add it every 5th character, you could simply throw an if statement inside of your while loop checking to see if count%5 = 0. If so, add the character, add to the counter, and move on.

Example:

```
While count <= Length.Text
    strpos = cc.Next(0, pool.Length)

    If count MOD 5 = 0 Then
        Result.Text = Result.Text & "-"
    End If

    Result.Text = Result.Text & pool(strpos)
    count = count + 1

End While
```

Comment: Ah, see, this is exactly what I figured. But the issue now is, I don't know how to exactly code that.

Comment: @NoNameBlank - for visual basic it's the [MOD function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx)

Comment: Just replace the "%" with " MOD " :)

Comment: I'm actually getting an error with this IF block.

If count MOD 5 == 0 Then
                Result.Text = Result.Text & "-"
            End If

I'm getting an error with "==" and Error List says "Expression Expected"

Comment: this may be a fail c# to VB conversion...try a single = sign

Comment: It's now working, but now I'm getting this as my result "9QNf-4iHWt-PnSKX-WNHr9-C4W53-4"  Only the first section is outputting four characters, which is messing up the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test it right now, but you can add "-" string once you have generated the random string. In this case you don't have to change your existing code. It's up to you decide which solutions suits better your needs.

```
Dim pos As Integer = 3
While pos < finalString.length
  finalString = finalString.insert(pos, "-")
  pos = pos + 5
End While
```

Basically, this solution use the `insert` method of the string class in VB.NET to add the "-" string every four characters.

Again, you have to test it yourself :)